# Adding desktop shortcuts to "My Computer" on Windows 2008 Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, desktop

Now that I've finnaly moved to doing some development/support work for Windows 2008 I find myself annoyed by the lack of one feature I just can't enable: the desktop shortcut to "My Computer" I've grown used to.  I know how to enable this on XP and 2003, but I just can't find the setting on 2008.

How can a user configure which desktop icons (My Computer, My Documents, Recycling Bin etc) on Windows 2008 Server?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Right click on the Computer menu item on the start menu, and select 'Show on Desktop' from the context menu that pops up.

Answer (score 6):

Create a Registry Editor file (`.reg` file) with the following content, and import it into the Registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]

"{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}"=dword:00000000

"{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"=dword:00000000

"{5399E694-6CE5-4D6C-8FCE-1D8870FDCBA0}"=dword:00000000
```